# excel application is not shown in task manager when It is opened

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am developing a little app that works with excel books, when I run it, it opens a excel book, I ran this code in windows  7 and the excel app was shown in task manager but I ran it again in windows 10 and a it was not shown in task manager.
I want it to be shown in task manager because sometimes the code crashes so I need to close the app from the task manager. I think it is a problem related to SO.
Do you know how to solve it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD7uD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b8bG.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaRvW.png)

Comment: It is there.  Task Manager was changed in Win10, programmers use the Processes tab to find stuff back.

Comment: @HansPassant -- Windows 7 as well.   In fact, hasn't there *always* been a ***Processes*** tab, as long as there's been CTRL+ALT+DEL?

Comment: Make sure that you are in the "More Details" view and select the "Processes" tab.  If Excel is not visible, but running, it will be listed under the "Background processes" grouping.

Comment: @TnTinMn Excel is not running in "Background processes", too. I am trying with other programs. Even Visual studio IDE is not. I think my SO is not working well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it, I just had to update the task manager by pressing the key F5 each time I run a new program, I think it is a bug.
Anyway, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Verify that the view update is not paused in Task Manager.  View Menu->Update Speed.

Comment: @TnTinMn yes, it is paused. I didn't realize that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

Open Powershell as admin and type get-process.  Verify that the Excel process is running, and type stop-process -Name Excel and press enter.

Good to go.

Comment: Very strange behavior. Before Windows 10, Excel.exe was appear in task manager when started from "Excel.Application" automation process from any external language. But now, it has disapparead from the task manager. So the solution of Rab is the good one.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're looking at the `Applications` tab, not going to the **`Processes`** tab.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>  .   <sub>(an alternative is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> on many systems.)</sub>
- Click **`Start Task Manager`**
- Click the **`Processes`** tab. (**#1** in the image below)
- Click  the Row Heading `Image Name` (to sort the processes alphabetically) (**#2** in image)
- Scroll down (**#3**) the list of images until you get to the 'E' section.
- If Excel is running, you will see *at least* one process named **`EXCEL.EXE`** (etc)

[image: Processes]

If you still can't find it, please take a screen shot of the Processes tab, and add it to your question, along with more of an explanation of why you think it should be showing.

Remember that the best way to remove all running processes and "refresh everything" is to reboot.  **Every computer should be rebooted *at least* once a day** -- or much more often than that when troubleshooting buggy programs.  Or in your case, **Reboot every time Excel crashes.**

### More Info:

- [Task Manager (Windows)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task_Manager_(Windows)#Summary_mode)

Comment: Your answer reads as though it is target toward VBA.  This question is tagged VB.Net and that entails a whole other set of concerns with instances not being released when programmers think they should be.

Comment: Dang! You're right!  That's twice in two days that I've done that!  Well the Task Manager part still applies, right?

Comment: @ashleedawg I have just updated my post, look at the three pictures please